# TQuery state in Delphi

Tags: delphi

With `TQuery.state in [dsEdit, dsInsert]` I can check if `DataSet` is in some of the given states. Is there a way to check if it is NOT in given states?

I have tried `TQuery.state <> [dsEdit, dsInsert]` resulting in `Incompatible types` error and `not Query.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]` but then I am getting error `Operator not applicable to this operand type`.

On the click on this button I am ApplyingUpdates, and I need to do that also when someone `delete` record from `DataSet` but there is not state that checks this case.

Comment: Aren't you looking for [UpdatesPending](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Bde.DBTables.TBDEDataSet.UpdatesPending) method? No, just kidding, get rid of BDE.

Comment: @Victoria as if it was my choice. They are using it on my job.

Comment: @Victoria, I was tempted to answer OPs other question about CachedUpdates yesterday, but have no experience with TQuery. There is no UpdatesPending for it, that is what you mean? I'm most experienced with some third-party DAC and the ways to approach OPs issues with the DAC I know I could not apply to TQuery.

Comment: @Nil, sorry, I meant property. No. Such property exists and should be public for `TQuery`. I meant that no one should be looking for anything for deprecated BDE. I was working with BDE many years ago just for a short time. The last sentence, however sounds like OP wants to determine whether there's something in the update cache, hence I've searched methods and properties of that component in help.

Comment: @Victoria totally agree on what I suspect the OP wants to know. And totally agree that UpdatesPending would help. I just couldn't find it yesterday in the documentation for TQuery, and read your comment as confirmation that it isn't applicable for TQuery.

Comment: @Nil with UpdatesPending I can not separate situations when user is trying to delete record from situations when he is trying to insert or edit.

Comment: @Victoria, aha, you want to detect update or insert and delete separately. I thought you care about any change. Sorry for misleading then :)

Comment: And you need to separate this because an insert could violate a PK constraint, cause errors somehow?

Comment: @Nil That's right. Just, here on my work, instead of PK constraint they are using Unique clustered index...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Of course.  A way to write this is

```
if not (Query1.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert]) then ....
```

The reason you get the `Operator not applicable to this operand type` error is because of operator precedence in Delphi's Object Pascal.  `Not` has a higher precedence than `Query1.State in [...]` so when the compiler sees `not Query1`, knowing that `Query1` is not a boolean, it raises the `Operator not applicable ...` error.

Comment: Logic. Thank you very much

Comment: While I think your answer and the resulting code is correct, I don't think the way you explain it is. The issue is that an element of an enumeration and a set of these elements can't be compared with the inequality operator.

Comment: @Nil.  Sorry, I disagree.  When the compiler sees the `not`, it switches into the state where it is expecting a boolean value, be it a variable reference, expression or whatever.  The next thing it sees is `Query1`, which is of type `TQuery`, not `boolean`, and that's why the `Operator not applicable` arises.  That's the reason to surround the set-membership expression (which **does** return a boolean), i.e, so that if considers `Query1.State in [...]` as a whole as the expression to negate, *not* the next token to encounters in the absence of the parentheses, i.e. `Query1`.

Comment: Yes, that is true. And I had missing brackets in the same situation too. But there is no `not` in the question. It reads `Query.state <> [dsEdit, dsInsert]`.

Comment: @Nil:  I was explaining my code, not the OP's, and that *does* contain '`not`.

Comment: I'm not a native speaker, so I might misunderstand. _The reason you get the Operator not applicable to this operand type error_. Is how you explain in your answer. And that's the same error the question complains about.

Comment: @Nil: You're misunderstanding. Martyn's answer is absolutely correct, and answers the question asked above.

Comment: MartynA and @KenWhite,I was wrong. I see now. What I supposed was the code generating the `Operator not applicable to this operand type` in the question (`Query.state <> [dsEdit, dsInsert]`) does in fact produce another error (`Incompatible types`). So Martyn deduced correctly what OP has done to experience the stated error. Sorry, my upvote then.